# MVVM DynamicObject + Entity Framework STE entities + Property Change Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, dynamicobject

I'm in the process of creating a BaseViewModel for my WPF projects, which is derived from DynamicObject, and I'm not really sure how to handle property changes to entities 'related' to the main entity (Navigation Properties of the main entity in the viewmodel).

For example:

VM:

```
 public class CustomerCRUDViewModel: BaseEntityViewModel<Customer>
    {
        ...
    }
```

This would be the VM for the Customer CRUD, for example. and the Customer entity for example has a navigation property called Address (an entity of type Address).

Now, the problem is, when binding the view to a property inside Address, changes are not reported to the VM, but to the entity directly, and therefore any behavior defined in the VM level is not triggered.

I know the explanation may not be clear enough, I just don't know how to explain myself better with my poor english.

My question is: how would the generic DynamicObject-based VM handle the scenario where I need to define behavior for properties no part of the main entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally Resolved this by Wrapping Navigation Properties with cached instances of BaseViewModels in the System.Dynamic.DynamicObject.TryGetMember 'getter' method. Not sure it was the most performant solution though, I can always strongly type my "Navigation view Models" in the derived entity view models.

Answer (score 0):

If your model - in this case Customer - implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, the viewMoodel could register to the Models `PropertyChanged` Event. This way the ViewModel gets informed about any property change taking place and could react accordingly.

Comment: That solution would need to subscribe to the Propertychanged events for each entity in the entire graph, which does not look too elegant to me. Besides, I don't like the fact of having to subscribe the VM to model events, because then I would need to subscribe and unsubscribe each time a different model is displayed. I am also looking for a generic solution that can be implemented in the framework-level (I mean the abstract generic BaseViewModel level)

Comment: You will need some kind of register/ unregister functionality anyways which must be part of your framework. But maybe this would be a more elegant approach:
 Consider introducing an interface such as  IModel which has a method e.g. RegisterCallback(Action callback) in order to get feedback from the model. This is better as there is only one Model communicating with one ViewModel. Then let the ViewModel register/ unregister a new callback, whenever a new model is introduced. Last but not least constraint the generic class definition to classes which implement IModel.